# How to add and format date in moment js

Tags: jquery, ajax, momentjs

How do I add time and format it to date format I wan't using moment js?
I tried this code :

```js
date_start = moment('11/21/2019').format('MMM. DD, YYYY');
```

but the browser telling me it was deprecated.

> provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Comment: Be more specific with the question so that we can answer and what do you exactly want ?

Comment: what is loan_term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add moment.js along with jquery to execute moment function. see below working example.

```js
var date_loan=new Date("11/21/2019");
date_start = moment(date_loan).format('MMM. DD, YYYY');
var monthadded= moment(date_loan).add(1,"M").format('MMM. DD, YYYY');
console.log(date_start)
console.log(monthadded)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please review the question

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera code updated. you need to pass Date object instead of string

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have say it very clear, you need to 'activate' moment before using it.

Using Javascript

**const moment from 'momentRoute'** and then...

```
date_start = moment(date_loan).format('MMM. DD, YYYY');
date_end = moment(date_loan).add(loan_term, 'M').format('MMM. DD, YYYY');
loan_end = moment(date_loan).add(loan_term, 'M').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: I dont get the asnwer